# How much of second-order arithmetic do you need for $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1$-determinacy to give you countable transitive models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory, reverse-math, determinacy

This is in some sense a follow-up to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450787/how-much-determinacy-do-you-need-for-second-order-arithmetic-to-be-as-strong-as) question.

The answer there says that over $\mathsf{Z}_2$ (second-order arithmetic), (boldface) $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1$-determinacy is enough to entail the existence of $0^{\sharp}$, which, if I'm understanding correctly, gives you the existence of a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (over just $\mathsf{Z}_2$).

Since the existence of a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is a single sentence, we know by compactness that only some fragment of $\mathsf{Z}_2 + \mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1\text{-Det}$ is necessary to entail the existence of a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, so I'm wondering whether one of the standard subsystems of second-order arithmetic is actually sufficient.

It's a classic result of Steel that open determinacy is equivalent to $\mathsf{ATR}_0$ over $\mathsf{RCA}_0$, so if we restrict attention to the big five, there's only really two options.

> **Question.** Does $\mathsf{RCA}_0 + \mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1\text{-Det}$ (equivalently $\mathsf{ATR}_0 + \mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1\text{-Det}$) entail the existence of a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$? If not does $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1\text{-}\mathsf{CA}_0+\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1\text{-Det}$ suffice?

I'm also curious about analogous questions regarding just consistency strength and possibly only considering (lightface) $\Sigma^1_1$-determinacy.

Comment: If memory serves, Yong Cheng has some work relevant to this. (EDIT: that may not be right, [Cheng/Schindler's paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43864232) seems less directly relevant than I remember.)

Comment: In fact $\Sigma^1_1\textsf{-Det}$ more or less trivially implies $\Sigma^1_2\textsf{-AC}_0$ (which in turn implies $\Pi^1_1\textsf{-CA}_0$): If a premise $\forall x\exists Y \varphi(x,Y)$, where $\varphi\in\Pi^1_1$ of the choice schema holds, then to prove the conclusion $\exists Y\forall x (\varphi(x,(Y)_x)$ consider the game where in the beginning the first player picks x and for the rest of the game the goal of the second player is to choose $Y$ satisfying $\varphi(x,Y)$, one bit per turn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathsf{RCA}_0 + \mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1\text{-Det}$ suffices to get sharps for all reals (and thus ctm of ZFC and more).

With boldface determinacy principles, we can bootstrap the background theory.  $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1\text{-Det}$ or just $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_1 \setminus \mathbf{\Sigma}^0_1 \text{-Det}$ gives $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1\text{-}\mathsf{CA}_0$.

If we need more, over $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1\text{-}\mathsf{CA}_0$, for every real $r$, $\Delta^1_1(r)$ determinacy is equivalent to existence for every $r$-recursive ordinal $α$ of a countable transitive model containing $r$ of KP + "$ω_α$ exists".  A detailed level-by-level correspondence can be found in "Calibrating Determinacy Strength in Borel Hierarchies" ([pdf](https://escholarship.org/content/qt6tk9351b/qt6tk9351b_noSplash_82b2a392eeaa5314b2f174d8d2ae832b.pdf)) by Sherwood Julius Hachtman (2015).

One then uses $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1\text{-Det}$ to get Harrington's principle (HP) for every real $r$ (i.e. for some real $r'$ (dependent on $r$), every $r'$-admissible ordinal is an $L[r]$ cardinal).  See for example "Analytic determinacy and 0^#.  A forcing-free proof of Harrington’s theorem" ([link](https://eudml.org/doc/212385)) by Ramez Sami (1999).  For more on HP, see the question you linked and also [Harrington's principle over higher order arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04000) by Cheng and Schindler (2015).

Finally, given a real $r$, choose $r'$ witnessing HP for $r$.  Next, using HP for $r'$, $L_{ω_1}[r']$ satisfies power set, and thus $r^\#$ exists in $L_{ω_1}[r']$ and hence in $V$.

By contrast, for lightface determinacy, we cannot just boostrap the background theory, raising interesting questions on how much background closure is needed and what happens without it.

Comment: Just to clarify, $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_1 \setminus \mathbf{\Sigma}^0_1 \text{-Det}$ is determinacy for differences of $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_1$ sets, right? Also does this need to be in Baire space (instead of Cantor space)?

Comment: @JamesHanson Yes, the determinacy levels don't match up for Cantor/Baire until a bit higher in the Borel hierarchy.

Comment: @JamesHanson Correct.  In the Cantor space, $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_1$ determinacy is equivalent to $\text{WKL}_0$, while $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_1 \setminus \mathbf{\Sigma}^0_1$ determinacy — $\text{ACA}_0$.